# Satellites in a row

Tags: observational-astronomy

I often watch the night sky in central North Dakota and love seeing satellites zooming by. Recently I saw a string of satellites traveling SW to NE. There were as many as 30 traveling one after the other. I’ve never seen this before and haven’t seen it since. They were at the same elevation as other satellites I’ve seen.
Do satellites travel in a string?

Comment: Sounds like Elon's been vandalising the sky again.